# App Policies: 10.1.4 Icon on Windows Store

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps

When I try to store my updated UWP app on Windows Store, I'm getting back report with notice:

> App Policies: 10.1.4 Icon
>
> Notes To Developer
>
> Icon assets must be provided in appropriate resolutions for all
>   targeted devices. For information on creating and providing the
>   appropriate icon assets, please see this page:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/app-assets

I generated icons automatically via Visual Assets in Package.appxmanifest file in UWP project in Visual Studio. Default icon resolution 400x400px.

Earlier versions were published without any problems.

Comment: Are you generated icons again or used the old generated icons?
I generated icons by Visual Assets many times, but it didn't occur the issue as you met.
Please read the document which the link directed in the back report,which provide many guidelines for icon asset.
Then, could you change another picture to try again, such as a higher pixel picture.

Answer (score 0):

Derive some guidance from this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a471d3aa-f7d3-455c-9536-ec958223b728/uwp-icon-assets-must-be-provided-in-appropriate-resolutions-for-all-targeted-devices?forum=windowsstore).

You should uncheck the “**apply recommended padding**” option and delete the icons you have then recreate them with Visual Assets.

After doing the above steps,you could check your Assets folder to see whether there are icons still left as the default icons.According to my situation, there two icons are being still left as the default icons, namely LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png and StoreLogo.backup.png. If they are default icons ,you can manually change them and try to submit again.